# mysql - sum multiple account balance

Tags: mysql

Currently I am working on a database model for an accounting firm, which they deal with multiple checkbook balance, and it needs to be printed out into one book.

As for now, it is showing the sum of numbers correctly:

```
set @nmr = 0;
select
@nmr:=@nmr+1 as "No.",
d.id_transaksi as "ID",
d.tgl_transaksi as "DATE",
e.tipe_transaksi as "TRANSACTION_CODE",
format(d.debit,0,'id_ID') as "DEBIT",
format(d.kredit,0,'id_ID') as "CREDIT",
format(sum(d.debit-d.kredit) over (partition by e.tipe_transaksi = "SS", d.id_anggota order by d.tgl_transaksi rows between unbounded preceding and current row),0,'id_ID') as "BALANCE A",
format(sum(d.debit-d.kredit) over (partition by e.tipe_transaksi = "SW", d.id_anggota order by d.tgl_transaksi rows between unbounded preceding and current row),0,'id_ID') as "BALANCE B"
from history_transaksi d, tipe_transaksi e
where d.id_anggota = 21
and e.tipe_transaksi = d.tipe_transaksi
order by "DATE" asc
```

note : TRANSACTION_CODE "SS" shown as BALANCE A, TRANSACTION_CODE "SW" shown as BALANCE B

[image: OUTPUT]

the problem is that I need the output shown like this, the BALANCE A will shown zero if user insert BALANCE B, vice versa

[image: OUTPUT_@]

Aprreciate all kinds of help. Feel free to correct me if there are any mistake. Thank you

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)